# Get data and insert in LazyColumn after API response (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, http, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I am completely new to Jetpack Compose AND Kotlin, but not to Android development in Java. Wanting to make first contact with both technologies, I wanted to make a really simple app which populates a LazyColumn with Text from an Api.

If I use a custom calendar to select a day of the week, I want to communicate with the server and receive a response from the data stored on that day of the week to associate it with the LazyColumn Composables.

I've created the TodoItem and TodoItemList functions, but I'm asking because I don't know how to connect the values by communicating with the server and receiving the data response.

**ReadTodoRequest.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest

import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface ReadTodoRequest {
    @GET("/todo/todo/")
    fun requestReadTodo(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Query("year") year: Int,
        @Query("month") month: Int,
        @Query("day") day: Int
        ): Call<ReadTodoResponse>
}
```

**ReadTodoResponse.kt**

```
package com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ReadTodoResponse(
    @SerializedName("resultCode")
    val resultCode: Int,
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: ArrayList<RToDoResponse>
)


// 응답값으로 data의 디테일한 값들
data class RToDoResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val year: Int,
    val month: Int,
    val day: Int,
    val done: Boolean,
    val writer: String
)
```

**TodoItem.kt**

```
 package com.example.todo_android.Component

import android.provider.Settings.Global.getString
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.content.res.TypedArrayUtils.getString
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse
import com.google.gson.JsonArray
import java.time.MonthDay
import java.time.Year

@Composable
fun TodoItem(Todo: ReadTodoResponse) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(12.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(80.dp)
            .background(color = Color.White)

    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Text(
                text = Todo.data.toString(),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoItemList(Todo: List<ReadTodoResponse>) {
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(items = Todo) { index, item ->
            TodoItem(Todo = item)
        }
    }
}
```

**CalendarScreen.kt**

```
    package com.example.todo_android.Screen

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.animation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.todo_android.Component.TodoItemList
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.CreateTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.ReadTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Data.Todo.UpdateTodo
import com.example.todo_android.Navigation.Action.RouteAction
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.CreateTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.DeleteTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.ReadTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Request.TodoRequest.UpdateTodoRequest
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.CreateTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.DeleteTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.ReadTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Response.TodoResponse.UpdateTodoResponse
import com.example.todo_android.Util.MyApplication
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.Kalendar
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.color.KalendarThemeColor
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.component.day.config.KalendarDayColors
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarDay
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarEvent
import com.himanshoe.kalendar.model.KalendarType
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

fun createTodo(token: String, year: String, month: String, day: String, title: String) {

    var createTodoResponse: CreateTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var createTodoRequest: CreateTodoRequest = retrofit.create(CreateTodoRequest::class.java)

    createTodoRequest.requestCreateTodo(token, CreateTodo(year, month, day, title))
        .enqueue(object : Callback<CreateTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CreateTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("error", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CreateTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<CreateTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                createTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("createTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("createTodo", "resultCode : " + createTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("createTodo", "data : " + createTodoResponse?.data)

            }
        })
}

fun readTodo(token: String, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {

    var readTodoResponse: ReadTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var readTodoRequest: ReadTodoRequest = retrofit.create(ReadTodoRequest::class.java)

    readTodoRequest.requestReadTodo(token, year, month, day)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<ReadTodoResponse> {

            //실패할 경우
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ReadTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("readTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            //성공할 경우
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ReadTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<ReadTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                readTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("readTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("readTodo", "resultCode : " + readTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("readTodo", "data : " + readTodoResponse?.data)
            }
        })
}

fun updateTodo(
    token: String,
    year: String,
    month: String,
    day: String,
    title: String,
    done: String,
) {

    var updateTodoResponse: UpdateTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var updateTodoRequest: UpdateTodoRequest = retrofit.create(UpdateTodoRequest::class.java)

    updateTodoRequest.requestUpdateTodo(token, UpdateTodo(year, month, day, title, done))
        .enqueue(object : Callback<UpdateTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UpdateTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("updateTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<UpdateTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<UpdateTodoResponse>,
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    updateTodoResponse = response.body()

                    Log.d("updateTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                    Log.d("updateTodo", "resultCode : " + updateTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                    Log.d("updateTodo", "data : " + updateTodoResponse?.data)
                } else {
                    Log.e("updateTodo", "resultCode : " + response.body())
                    Log.e("updateTodo", "code : " + response.code())
                }
            }
        })
}

fun deleteTodo(
    token: String,
) {
    var deleteTodoResponse: DeleteTodoResponse? = null

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://plotustodo-ctzhc.run.goorm.io/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var deleteTodoRequest: DeleteTodoRequest = retrofit.create(DeleteTodoRequest::class.java)

    deleteTodoRequest.requestDeleteTodo(token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<DeleteTodoResponse> {

            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("updateTodo", t.message.toString())
            }

            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<DeleteTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                deleteTodoResponse = response.body()

                Log.d("deleteTodo", "token : " + MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", ""))
                Log.d("deleteTodo", "resultCode : " + deleteTodoResponse?.resultCode)
                Log.d("deleteTodo", "data : " + deleteTodoResponse?.data)
            }
        })
}


@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun CalendarScreen(routeAction: RouteAction) {

    val states = listOf(
        "월간",
        "주간"
    )
    var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(states[1]) }

    val onSelectionChange = { text: String -> selectedOption = text }

    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val token = "Token ${MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", "")}"

//    val year = "2023"
//    val month = "2"
//    val day = "6"
//    val token = "Token ${MyApplication.prefs.getData("token", "")}"
//    val title = "qkrwhdwns"
//    val done = "true"

    var year by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var month by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var day by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val todoList = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<ReadTodoResponse>()
    }

    val title = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val done = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                .background(Color(0xffe9e9ed))
                .padding(4.dp)
        )
        {
            states.forEach { text ->
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    color =
                    if (text == selectedOption) {
                        Color.Black
                    } else {
                        Color.Gray
                    },
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                        .clickable {
                            onSelectionChange(text)
                            isVisible = !isVisible
                        }
                        .background(
                            if (text == selectedOption) {
                                Color.White
                            } else {
                                Color(0xffe9e9ed)
                            }
                        )
                        .padding(
                            vertical = 5.dp,
                            horizontal = 16.dp,
                        )
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(29.dp))

        AnimatedVisibility(isVisible)
        {
            Kalendar(
                kalendarType = KalendarType.Oceanic(),
                kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                    headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                    year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                    month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                    day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth


                    todoList.clear()

                    readTodo(token, year, month, day)
                })
        }

        AnimatedVisibility(!isVisible) {
            Kalendar(
                kalendarType = KalendarType.Firey,
                kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                    headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                    year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                    month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                    day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth

                    todoList.clear()

                    readTodo(token, year, month, day)
                })
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(29.dp))

        Text(text = day.toString())

        TodoItemList(Todo = todoList)


//        Scaffold(floatingActionButton = {
//            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
//                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "todolist 추가")
//            }
//        }) {
//            LazyColumn {
//                TodoItem()
//            }
//        }

//        Surface(
//            shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .wrapContentSize()
//        ) {}


//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { readTodo(token, year, month, day) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 조회", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { createTodo(token, year, month, day, title) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 작성", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { updateTodo(token, year, month, day, title, done) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 수정", color = Color.Black)
//        }
//
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
//
//        Button(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .width(300.dp)
//                .height(50.dp),
//            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFFBE3C7)),
//            onClick = { deleteTodo(token) }
//        ) {
//            Text(text = "TODO 삭제", color = Color.Black)
//        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that might be helpful.

1. You can use `val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()` in `@Composable` to create a coroutine scope that jobs will be canceled automatically when @Composable dispose. Then you can use it like `onClick = { scope.launch{ /*do network request here*/ }}`
2. For a list, if you want to refresh the UI when its size changes, you can choose `val todos = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }`. In that case, when you call `todos.add`, the UI can be updated successfully.
3. If you want to modify `todos` in your `TodoItem`, you may write it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TodoItem(
    item: TodoItemBean,
    deleteAction: () -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = deleteAction) {
        Text("delete")
    }
}

fun deleteTodo(
    token: String,
    onSuccess: () -> Unit,
    onFail: (e: Throwable) -> Unit
) {
    /**
     * deleteTodoRequest.requestDeleteTodo(token)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<DeleteTodoResponse> {
        
            // 실패 했을때
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                onFail(t)
            }
        
            // 성공 했을때
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DeleteTodoResponse>,
                response: Response<DeleteTodoResponse>,
            ) {
                deleteTodoResponse = response.body()
                if(deleteTodoResponse.code == 200){ onSuccess() }
                else { onFail(...) }
            }
       }
     */
}
@Composable
fun TodoList() {
    val todos = remember { mutableStateListOf<TodoItemBean>() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LazyColumn {
        items(todos){ item ->
            TodoItem(item = item, deleteAction = {
                scope.launch {
                    deleteTodo("token", onSuccess = {
                        todos.remove(item)
                    }, onFail = {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    })
                    
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: how abt readTodo?

Comment: You can use `producedState` to initialize todos.

Comment: Or use `LaunchedEffect`. You can search the usage of these two APIs by yourself. They are not difficult.

Comment: idk how to link to retrofit response and LazyColumn

Comment: Just like what I showed in `deleteTodo`, add `onSuccess` and `onFail` callback lambda in `readTodos`(which returns all todos we have, I believe you can write it). Then use it in Composable like:

Comment: fun readTodos(
    token: String,
    onSuccess: (List<TodoItemBean>) -> Unit,
    onFail: (e: Throwable) -> Unit
){

}

fun TodoList() {
    val todos = remember { mutableStateListOf<TodoItemBean>() }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        readTodos("token", onSuccess = {
            todos.addAll(it)
        }, onFail = {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load all", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
}

If you want to refer to a more complex example:[here](http://gg.gg/132nmp)

Comment: what is "TodoItemBean"? is it response data like "ReadTodoResponse" class on my project?

Comment: It is a custom entity class representing a `Todo Item`. Like `data class TodoItemBean(val description: String, val createTime: Date)`. It can be constructed from Response, or it is just your `ReadTodoResponse` (depending on your design).

Comment: i edited my code posted it on stackoverflow. there are not error but the list of LazyColumn composable are does not see it,,,